# How do I make my website's logo carousel continuous? Right now it moves to the left every 2-3 seconds and pauses for a few seconds before starting

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I'm looking to make the logo carousel continuous. Also, there's a delay for the carousel starting when the page is first loaded. I'm not exactly sure how to approach this, as I didn't use slick. Thanks everyone!!

Here's my js:

```js
//imports

function LogoCarousel() {

  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    loop: 1000000,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplayspeed: 0,
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: true

    

  };

  return (
    <Slider {...settings}>
      <div className="logo-slide">
        <img className="logo-image1" src={logo1} />
      </div>

      <div className="logo-slide">  
        <img className="logo-image2" src={logo2} />
      </div>

      <div className="logo-slide">  
        <img className="logo-image3" src={logo3} />
      </div>

      <div className="logo-slide">  
        <img className="logo-image4" src={logo4} />
      </div>

      <div className="logo-slide">  
        <img className="logo-image5" src={logo5} />
      </div>

      <div className="logo-slide">  
        <img className="logo-image6" src={logo6} />
      </div>
    </Slider>
  );

}

export default LogoCarousel;
```

and my css

```css
.logo-carousel {
  animation: scroll 15s linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); } 
}


.logo-carousel img {
  max-width: 120px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.logo-carousel img.active {
  transform: scale(1.2); 
}
.logo-slide {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
}

.logo-image1 {
  max-width: 120px;

}

.logo-image2 {
  max-width: 120px;

}

.logo-image3 {
  max-width: 120px;

}

.logo-image4 {
  max-width: 120px;
}

.logo-image5 {
  max-width: 120px;
}

.logo-image6 {
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

I tried lining up the autoplay speed and speed, but there's still an initial delay and it's not constant/continuous.

Comment: Can you please make the demo page in codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: @Ashish SO asks that code be placed in the question (so it is there for future readers). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I was talking about this kind of tool usage: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do
Using this it is easy to debug. Above code is without including js libraries and many more things missing.